# Let p be prime and let $Y_p = 2^p − 1. $ Show $Y_p$ is either prime or 2-pseudoprime.

Tags: number-theory

Let p be prime and let $Y_p = 2^p − 1.$   Show $Y_p$ is either prime or 2-pseudoprime.

I have shown $Y_p-1$ is a multiple of $p$ and don't know where to go with this.

Comment: This immediately follows from Fermat's little theorem. For prime $p$ and positive integer $n$ , we have $n^p\equiv n\mod p$ , hence $p|n^p-n$. With $n=2$, you get $p|2^p-2=(2^p-1)-1$